# Trouble with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having trouble with Recyclerview. I have my recyclerView ID as `recyclerView_main` but its not accepting it in my mainActivity class it shows an error that it does not exist. I am stuck and cant proceed with creating a list manager.

P.S: I was following a tutorial where the person used the ID in his `onCreate` method to change background colour and it worked for him. Also, my mainActivity is empty.

These are my dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Today"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:text="Word of the day is: Renegade"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="404dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Today" />
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not exist"? Are you getting an error for `R.id.recyclerView_main` while you're coding? Or are you getting a runtime Exception? In either case, please post the exact error message.

Comment: @Asher please follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) ... also, if you've an error, just paste the needed code only and the stacktrace

Comment: try cleaning or rebuilding your project. sometimes android studio creates such problems. it had happens a lot with me

Answer (score 2):

MainActivity Or main2Activity.. ??
It is not About RecyclerView it is about

`tools:context=".Main2Activity"`

remove above line from layout file and then clean build your project.. and then try to run again.